# Generic incompatibility boundary issue in Arrays.sort method

Tags: java, generics

When I use `Arrays.sort` to sort an array, I use the following 4 examples:

```
String[] strings = new String[10];
// fill strings array
Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.naturalOrder());
Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.reverseOrder());
Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed());          // Compile Error
Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.<String>naturalOrder().reversed());
```

They all call this method, which needs **`T[]`** and **`Comparator<? super T>`**:

```
<T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c);
```

*The third example has compilation errors.* The IDE instructed me to provide **`String[]`** and **`Comparator<T>`**, and the reason given was **`no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to T`**. When I run it, I get the following error message:

```
inference variable T has incompatible bounds
 lower bounds: T,java.lang.Object
 lower bounds: java.lang.String
```

But in fact, **the return types of `naturalOrder`, `reverseOrder` and `reversed` are all `Comparator<T>`. The difference is that `naturalOrder`, `reverseOrder` have the restrictions on T, but `reversed` does not.**

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder() {}
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {}
Comparator<T> reversed() {}
```

So

1. How to explain the **incompatibility boundary** here?
2. Why is only the third example wrong? If it is because of **the type restriction of `T`**, then how does the type restriction work?

Comment: Java's compiler can't do type inference through method chains. It would be technically possible for your 3rd example to compile with the current generic type arguments - it is unambiguous what you want; it just doesn't. Maybe in the future that will work. Right now, you have to help out the type inference system with a type witness (the `<String>` part).

Comment: See the linked question as well

Comment: Yes, just what Michael said. Generic type inference is not an easy task when 'transferred' through method chains, especially when it has different upper and lower bounds (i.e. using `? super T` or `? extends T`).

Comment: To address your first question, `reversed()` is an *instance method* referring to the interface’s type parameter. There is no incompatibility here, as *uses* of a type parameter never repeat the bounds. (In contrast, the `static` methods *declare* a type parameter.) Calling `reversed()` on a `Comparator<WhatEver>` will return a `Comparator<WhatEver>` as the return type of `reversed()` is bound to the same type parameter as the object you’re calling the method on. So the declaration of `reversed()` does not make the 3rd example wrong, it’s the limited type inference, as explained by Michael.